# why TS requires single arg to call one of two functions with different parameter count?

Tags: typescript, optional-parameters

Given the code

```js
const funcs = {
    f1: (s: string) => {},
    f2: (s1: string, s2?: string) => {},
    f3: (s1?: string, s2?: string) => {}
};

funcs['' as 'f1' | 'f2']('x', 'y');   // OK
funcs['' as 'f1' | 'f3']('x', 'y');   // Expected 1 arguments, but got 2.
```

why TS requires exactly one argument for function merged from `f1`, `f3`?

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgVzMCMC8MDeAoGf4CMAXDABQQnQBOAlmAOYCU6AfFjAL4A0u+cATCXLEY1OvS6j+AfkpRaDZmjaZOPfPADMQiAVmj54yRBlyFTVuw7YOAbmzZQkWHAL908JCgDaAcl8wAIaovq4BAD4wofy+ALr2APQJGgB60tiu-KS+AB6+kr4Anr6MtvhJMADyANKO4NCEmh6IyBB+AcFRYTCRoZpx2BX4aRkEmtl5BcWl5ckAojkADgCmwFDLACYwBEFU9AgAtstgUBCSAEYIsPQgsPwAdNhAA)

Comment: Looks like a TS bug/limitation to me, but I haven't found an existing issue about it.  https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29011 is what implemented calling unions of functions, and I'd expect this to synthesize something like `(s1: string, s2?: string) => {}` but I don't see that happening.  Maybe someone wants to file a (properly formatted) issue?